# How to convert an MKV file without crackling

Tags: conversion, audio, avi, matroska, video-conversion

I'm trying to convert an MKV file to AVI format. I've tried different settings and there is always a slight crackling in the background. Why does this happen? How can I convert an MKV file to a different video format while preserving the sound quality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ffmpeg -i filename.mkv -vcodec copy -acodec copy output.avi` should do it, see Ignacio's answer.  he's right, this is just the command to support his answer

Comment: The conversion worked and the sound problem isn't there anymore. However, I noticed that the playback isn't smooth anymore. Why could that be?

Comment: maybe avi container doesn't like the framerate-correction keyframe issue probably

Comment: you could try ffmpeg -i filename.mkv -sameq -acodec copy output.avi

Comment: that should resync everything and keep the quality

Comment: That produces a slightly bigger file than the other command, so I'm assuming it preserves the quality better. The video playback is still a little bit jerky though. I fixed it by doing a second conversion using ffmpeg -i output.avi -vcodec mpeg4 -b 4000k -acodec mp2 -ab 320k converted.avi. For some reason if I try to do this directly from the original file the resulting file has problems. It has to first be converted to avi and then this second conversion can be done. Do you know why that is?

Comment: it doesn't preserve the quality better, it is almost exactly the same quality.  it just re-renders the video and to keep the same quality the size grows...copy is EXACTLY the same.  jerkiness going away is the re-encode of both channels and resync.  I was trying to get around re-encoding for all the keyframe and audio syncing stuff.  it might be that avi and mkv support different size slices between keyframes, so the copy of media gets jerky because it thinks the slice is done when there's more data.  that could explain the popping.  that happens sometimes when you release and grab a soundcard

Comment: so...moving to avi with copies of the streams makes sure that the release grab doesn't happen.  then operating on the streams inside of avi keeps ffmpeg from letting go of the soundcard i guess.  if it happens i would think that the mkv container holds slices as independent audio files that correspond to video(flv containers do this sometimes)

Answer (score 2):

Converting from one container to another does not affect the quality of the contents. You may be suffering from underruns though, where the codec suddenly runs out of data to convert. Check your mux/interleave settings.

Comment: There are settings which affect quality for both audio and video, so I don't see how they're not affected. What kinds of settings should I be looking for?

Comment: @Linux Jedi I think he means if you specify sameq etc.  the container has nothing to do with codec or bitrate.

Comment: I don't think my computer is underpowered. That shouldn't make a difference though, right? It will just take longer to convert, is that correct? What's sameq? You mean same quality? I tried that and it doesn't really make a difference?

Comment: the -sameq flag is for video...there's a similar switch for audio i think....but it means don't transcode audio at all just duplicate the stream...don't remember atm...it's in the man page...correction not in the man page just checked, but i know i used it once...google

Comment: What program are you talking about?

Comment: ffmpeg is the program

Comment: -acodec copy is the one

Comment: @Linux: Obviously if you play with the audio and video settings this can change the quality. But then again, you'd be doing more than just changing the container.